# Problems using the given bag in the vlsam-tutorial

Tags: ros, vslam, vslam-system

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I've installed the vslam via

> sudo apt-get install
> ros-diamondback-vslam

and tried to run the bag file given in the tutorial
[Tutorials/RunningVslamOnStereoData](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam_system/Tutorials/RunningVslamOnStereoData)

If is start the bag-file I only get

```
[ERROR] [1309158942.182362673]: Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/right/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.
[ERROR] [1309158942.295048099]: Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/left/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.
```

Was there a change in the code which is not reflected in the bag-file?

Nikolas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10405/problems-using-the-given-bag-in-the-vlsam-tutorial/) by [NikolasEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/652/nikolasengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2011-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Nikolas,

I think I had the same problem: the bag file was probably recorded using cturtle and you are probably running diamondback. In any case, you may try to fix the bag file:

rosbag fix vslam_tutorial.bag vslam_tutorial_fixed.bag

and play it as follows:

rosbag play --clock vslam_tutorial_fixed.bag

Regards

Jordi

---

Originally posted by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) with karma: 245 on 2011-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NikolasEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/652/nikolasengelhard/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks. no highlighting in comment, so see next answer...